# CKEditor excessive formatting of plain text

Tags: php, linux, ckeditor

**The problem:**

CKEditor is adding tons of `<span>` tags to plain text, such as the example below.

**The code:**

The setup is a php page, calling ckeditor and saving entries into a PostgreSQL table. I believe most settings on CKEditor is default. Here's some of the code:

```
include ('./ckeditor/ckeditor.php') ;
$CKEditor = new CKEditor() ;
$CKEditor->returnOutput = true;
$CKEditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/';
$CKEditor->config['width'] = 560;
$CKEditor->config['height'] = 300;
$CKEditor->textareaAttributes =
                array("cols" => 90, "rows" => 70);
$CKEditor->config['DefaultLanguage'] = "sv" ;
//$CKEditor->config['EnterMode'] = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
$config['toolbar'] = array(
        array( 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', '-' ),
        array( 'Image', 'Link', 'Unlink', '-', 'Table', 'NumberedList','BulletedList' )
);
$config['skin'] = 'v2';
```

**Example input/output (in source):**

The input:

```
En hel del av er
```

Becomes:

```
En <span data-scayt_word="hel" data-scaytid="2">hel</span> del 
<span data-scayt_word="av" data-scaytid="3">av</span> 
<span data-scayt_word="er" data-scaytid="4">er</span>
```

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way: disable the spellchecker (scayt - spellcheck as you type)

```
$CKEditor->config['removePlugins'] ='scayt'; // comma separated if many
```

[How to remove unused plugins](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.removePlugins)

If you want to leave SCAYT available, but prevent the feature from being turned on automatically:

```
$CKEditor->config['scayt_autoStartup'] = false;
```

But this is strange behavior, how do you retrieves the content from ckeditor instance? Just try to get data from firebug to see the not dirty content:

```
console.log( CKEDITOR.instances.your_instance_name.getData() );
```

Comment: I have not written the php myself, but I am getting more and more sure that it is inserting the string directly into the db and not calling `getData()`.

Comment: I have been beating my head against this code for hours now, can't make out how he is getting the data from ckeditor. He has a function `changeNews`, where `$summary` is inserted as-is into the db, but I cannot see that he ever calls this function.

Comment: Ah, here we go. `$summary = $_POST["summary"] ;` So, that get's set somewhere, I just need to find that place.

Comment: So you have standard php integration, no ajax data savings, etc. Your toolbar does not contain spellcheck, so just disable it (scayt) in config. CKEditor has autosave function when just after the any change data from wysiwyg iframe synchronizes with textarea. When this fired all messy code should be cleaned but scayt in some reason do not do it. All available params of scayt [here](http://www.webspellchecker.net/v3/samples/scayt_ckeditor_plugin.html)

Comment: I finally got it to work. Just with the "false" on startup. At first, when I was testing it, it did not seem to be working, but that was (probably) because I cut & paste a sample, and somehow ckeditor brought along the hidden tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

overkill to to turn the plug-in off if you still want it you can clean the  output like so in php:

```
$output = preg_replace('/<span data-scayt_word="[^"]+" data-scaytid="[0-9]*">([^<]+)<\/span>/','$1',$input);
```

*credit to balrok for the regX

Comment: The problem is that the code uses the raw data instead of the getData() function. Spelling is irrelevant, since the posts will be in swedish, and I don't think scayt is installed with a swedish language pack.

Comment: @TLP "getData() Gets the editor data. The data will be in raw format. It is the same data that is posted by the editor. " same as posted - yup im looking at it again.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, if you want to clean up the html-source you can use this sed command:

```
cat scaytPolluted.html | sed -r 's/<span data-scayt_word="[^"]+" data-scaytid="[0-9]*">([^<]+)<\/span>/\1/g' > clean.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, the data is inserted into a db directly, so there is no way to apply such a solution. However, the problem is solved, I simply turned scayt off, as mentioned in the comments. The problem is using the raw data of CKeditor, rather than the getData() function.